# Iteration through dictionary pulling the wrong value for searched key

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, iteration

I've used Pandas to read an excel sheet that has two columns used create a key, value dictionary. When ran, the code will search for a key, and produce it's value. Ex: WSO-Exchange will be equal to 52206.

[image]

Although, when I search for 59904-FX's value, it returns 35444 when I need it to return 22035; It only throws this issue when a key is also a value later on. Any ideas on how I can fix this error? I'll attach my code below, thanks!

```
MapDatabase = {}
    for i in Mapdf.index:
        MapDatabase[Mapdf['General Code'][i]] = Mapdf['Upload Code'][i]
```

*df["AccountID"][i] is reading another excel sheet to search if that cell is in the dictionary's keys, and if it is, then to change it to it's value.*

```
for i in df.index:
    for key, value in MapDatabase.items():
        if str(df['AccountId'][i]) == str(key):
            df['AccountId'][i] = value
```

Comment: You should probably provide a sample of your data too.

Comment: What is the index of the DataFrame?  When you read in the Excel file, what are you telling pandas to use as the index?

Comment: @PaSTE the index is the value being searched for in the MapDatabase dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, I meant what is the code you are using to read in the Excel file that generates `Mapdf`, and what are the columns to the left of "General Code" and "Upload Code"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Turns out I didn't need to do a nested for loop. The solution was to go from a for loop to an if statment.

```
for i in df.index:
    if str(df['AccountId'][i]) in str(MapDatabase.items()):
        df.at[i, 'AccountId'] = MapDatabase[df['AccountId'][i]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the [xlrd](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/) library to do this:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

workbook = open_workbook("data.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

data = {sheet.cell(row, 0).value: sheet.cell(row, 1).value for row in range(sheet.nrows)}

print(data)
```

Which gives the following dictionary:

```
{'General Code': 'Upload Code', '59904-FX': 22035.0, 'WSO-Exchange': 52206.0, 56476.0: 99875.0, 22035.0: 35444.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Check the Index for Duplicates in Your Excel File

Most likely the problem is that you are iterating over a non-unique index of the DataFrame `Mapdf`.  Check that the first column in the Excel file you are using to build `Mapdf` is unique per row.

### Don't Iterate Over DataFrame Rows

However, rather than trying to iterate row-wise over a DataFrame (which is almost always the wrong thing to do), you can build the dictionary with a call to the [dict constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict), handing it an iterable of (key, value) pairs:

```
MapDatabase = dict(zip(Mapdf["General Code"], Mapdf["Upload Code"]))
```

### Consider Merging Rather than Looping

Better yet, what you are doing seems like an ideal candidate for [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).
 It looks like what you want to do is overwrite the values of `AccountId` in `df` with the values of `Upload Code` in `Mapdf` if `AccountId` has a match in `General Code` in `Mapdf`.  That's a mouthful, but let's break it down.

First, merge `Mapdf` onto `df` by the matching columns (`df["AccountId"]` to `Mapdf["General Code"]`):

```
columns = ["General Code", "Upload Code"]  # only because it looks like there are more columns you don't care about
merged = df.merge(Mapdf[columns], how="left", left_on = "AccountId", right_on="General Code")
```

Because this is a [left join](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types), rows in `merged` where column `AccountId` does not have a match in `Mapdf["General Code"]` will have missing values for `Upload Code`.  Copy the non-missing values to overwrite `AccountId`:

```
matched = merged["Upload Code"].notnull()
merged.loc[matched, "AccountId"] = merged.loc[matched, "Upload Code"]
```

Then drop the extra columns if you'd like:

```
merged.drop(["Upload Code", "General Code"], axis="columns", inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips @PaSTE, although this doesn't solve the issue. I tried removing the duplicates, attempted the dict zip, and the merge of columns but still nothing. I'm assuming it has something to do with this bit of code: 'for i in df.index:
    for key, value in MapDatabase.items():
        if str(df['AccountId'][i]) == str(key):
            df['AccountId'][i] = value'